# Determine which elements in a list are NOT in another list

Tags: c#, ilist

I have two `IList<CustomObject>`, where `CustomObject` has a `Name` property that's a `string`. Call the first one `set`, and the second one `subset`. `set` contains a list of things that I just displayed to the user in a multiselect list box. The ones the user selected have been placed in `subset` (so `subset` is guaranteed to be a subset of `set`, hence the clever names ;) )

What is the most straightforward way to generate a third `IList<CustomObject>`, `inverseSubset`, containing all the CustomObjects the user DIDN'T select, from these two sets?

I've been trying LINQ things like this

```
IEnumerable<CustomObject> inverseSubset = set.Select<CustomObject,CustomObject>(
    sp => !subset.ConvertAll<string>(p => p.Name).Contains(sp.Name));
```

...based on answers to vaguely similar questions, but so far nothing is even compiling, much less working :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the LINQ [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) for this:

> Produces the set difference of two sequences.

Comment: It would be helpful to say that he needs to implement the `IEquatable<T>` generic interface and provide his own `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods for `CustomObject`.

Comment: Actually, since both sets contain references to the same objects I didn't. `IEnumerable<CustomObject> inverseSubset = set.Except<CustomObject>(subset);` worked just fine.

Answer (score -1):

Aha, too much SQL recently - I didn't want `Select`, I wanted `Where`:

```
List<string> subsetNames = subset.ConvertAll<string>(p => p.Name);
IEnumerable<CustomObject> inverseSubset =
    set.Where<CustomObject>(p => !subsetNames.Contains(p.Name));
```

Comment: OK, it's not as slick as `Except`, but why the down voting? If I actually had to filter on just the Name property I don't think Except would work, would it?